# SharePoint 2019 javascript SP.MoveCopyUtil.copyFile not working across site collections

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-on-prem, copy

In SharePoint 2016, I was happily surprised to benefit new javascript functions available in SharePoint : SP.MoveCopyUtil.* to get out of the hell of copying files in SharePoint.

The following peace of code was working like a charm :
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
SP.MoveCopyUtil.copyFile(context,fileUrl,destUrl);

even when destUrl being in another site collection.

Unfortunately, after the migration to SharePoint 2019, it does not work anymore. It works only if destUrl is in the same site collection. How can I do? I there a problem with SharePoint 2019 js files?

Comment: Hi. I did not have the time to take into account the last advice somebody gave me; and, surprise: answers have disappeared ! :-( Sorry for having been silent so long....